# How do I get data from my custom module table?

Tags: database, module, magento-1, getmodel

I have a custom module with its own table which saves the date inside the column named `date_to`.

I am trying to access the values from only this column but when I load the collection and call `getData('date_to')` I get the whole collection and not just the `date_to` column.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
$date = Mage::getModel('namespace_modulename/tablename')->getData('date_to');

print_r($date);
```

When I do `print_r($date);` I get the whole collection even though I have specified in parenthesis the I only want the date_to column values.

I know I'm missing out an important piece and would like for some help please.

Comment: try `getDateTo()` like `Mage::getModel('namespace_modulename/tablename')->getDateTo()`

Comment: @TimHallman thaks for your input, I get `null` returned when I use `getDateTo()` even though there are values in that colum...

Comment: @TimHallman yes, I get an error `Call to undefined method Namespace_Module_Model_Resource_Custom_Data_Collection::getDateTo()`

Comment: So when you do `echo '<pre>';print_r($date);echo '</pre>';` do you see the `date_to` object or method?

Comment: @TimHallman Yes I get the object, `namespace_modulename/tablename [_resourceModel:protected] => date_to [_resource:protected] `

Comment: Ahh, try `Mage::getResourceModel('namespace_modulename/tablename')->getDateTo();` or maybe `Mage::getModel('namespace_modulename/tablename')->getResource()->getData('date_to')`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for the help, I had to loop over the collection like below:

```
$date = Mage::getModel('namespace_modulename/tablename');

$collection = $date->getCollection();
foreach($collection as $date_to){
    print_r($date_to->getData());
    print_r($date_to->getDateTo());
}
```

Comment: can i write this code on controller file

Answer (score 1):

Try doing

```
$date = Mage::getModel('namespace_modulename/tablename')->load($id);

print_r($date->getData('date_to'));
```

where $id is the primary key.