# magento : how to get custom table value

Tags: magento-1.9

I have custom table register_otp, in that column name is_verify
Table like this

```
        id   random_code   customer_id  is_verify

         1     Abs            15          0
         2     cfd            18          1
```

How to get value of is_verify based on customer id

Comment: Please refer to this links: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/107997/how-to-get-data-from-custom-table  and this one https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/69356/how-do-i-get-data-from-my-custom-module-table

Comment: but here where is table _name

Comment: Those links that i send to you earlier. You can get an idea on how to display custom table value on your magento site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$connectionresource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');   
$readconnection = $connectionresource->getConnection('core_read'); 

$allrecord = $readconnection->select()->from(array('register_otp'=>'register_otp'));

$alldata =$readconnection->fetchAll($allrecord);

foreach($alldata as $is_verify)
   {
     echo $is_verify['is_verify'];
   }
```

you can get all data with this query